# How to open a new activity when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making an android app and I want it so that when someone clicks a button in the main menu activity, they are taken to the corresponding activity. At the moment my code is:

1. button in menu xml:

   ```
   <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Dwight Quotes"
   android:id="@+id/DwightButton"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:onClick="openNewActivity"
   android:background="#EAD383"
   android:enabled="false" />
   ```
2. the menu java:

   ```
   public void openNewActivity(View view) {
   // Do something in response to button
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dwight.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

when I click the button nothing happens. Can someone explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove **android:enabled="false"** from your code.

Comment: what does this statement do actually?

Comment: thank you very much, such a stupid mistake on my part.